# How to use 2.5mm A/V output of intercom device to capture video stream/images in Raspberry Pi3 Model B?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have intercom device which has 2.5mm A/V output. I want to use this output to capture video/ images in my Rasp PI3

I have already searched on internet regarding different cables but found very few matching my requirement.

I would like to know different ways to use 2.5mm AV output with raspberry pi3.

[image]

Comment: *"2.5mm"* is a linear dimension.  Perhaps this is the diameter of a connector?  The proper way to describe or specify an *"A/V output"* is by the format of the electrical signal(s), and not by the size of the connector .

Comment: i don't know the signal format as i've never used this output .. but for reference i added an image of my intercom device in my description above.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 2.5mm phono minijack with 4 conductors: tip, ring1, ring2, and shaft. One of those is ground, one is power, one is one channel of analog audio (like a white, or red, RCA connector) and one is analog composite video, like a yellow RCA connector.

There are USB analog A/V capture dongles that can be made to work with the Raspberry Pi, such as this one: https://www.febon.net/products/usb20-febon264-uvc-cvbs-capture-card

So get one of those, get it working, and then solder together your own custom 2.5mm phono minijack to RCA cable.